# How to mount the folder as volume that docker image build creates?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume, persistent-volumes

The docker-compose file is as follows:

```
version: "3"

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfile_backend
    image: backend:dev1.0.0
    entrypoint: ["sh", "-c"]
    command: python manage.py runserver
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
```

The docker build creates a folder lets say `/docker_container/configs` which has files like `config.json` and `db.sqlite3`. The mounting of this folder as volumes is necessary because during runtime the content of the folder gets modified or updated,these changes should not be lost.

I have tried adding a volumes as follows  :

```
    volumes:
      - /host_path/configs:/docker_container/configs
```

Here the problem is mount point of the hostpath(`/host_path/configs`) is empty initially so the container image folder(`/docker_container/configs`) also gets empty. 
How could this problem be solved?.

Comment: In Docker, it's often easier to use a database in an external container than to use SQLite, for pretty much exactly this reason.

Comment: Thanks. Please suggest if any alternate options solution available for this problem other than using an external container for database.

Answer (score 4):

You are using a [Bind Mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) which will "hide" the content already existing in your image as you describe - `/host_path/configs` being empty, `/docker_container/configs` will be empty as well.

You can use [named Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container) instead which will automatically populate the volume with content already existing in the image and allow you to perform updates as you described:

```
services:
  backend:
    # ...
    #
    # content of /docker_container/configs from the image
    # will be copied into backend-volume
    # and accessible at runtime
    volumes:
    - backend-volume:/docker_container/configs

volumes:
  backend-volume:
```

As stated in [the Volume doc](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container):

> If you start a container which creates a new volume [...] and the container has files or directories in the directory to be mounted [...] the directory’s contents are copied into the volume

Comment: Thanks for suggestion to use `named volumes`, but i would want to have volume contents in a particular path may be hostpath or nfs mount path. Using named volume will it be possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can pre-populate the host directory once by copying the content from the image to directory.

```
 docker run --rm backend:dev1.0.0 tar -cC /docker_container/config/ . | tar -xC /host_path/configs
```

Then start your compose project as it is and the host path already has the original content from the image.

---

Another approach is to have an entrypoint script that copies content to the mounted volume.

You can mount the host path to a different path(say `/docker_container/config_from_host`) and have an entrypoint script which copies content from `/docker_container/configs` into `/docker_container/config_from_host` if the directory is empty.

Sample pseudo code:

```
$ cat Dockerfile
  RUN cp entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
  CMD /entrypoint.sh

$ cat entrypoint.sh:
   #!/bin/bash
   if /docker_container/config_from_host is empty; then
        cp -r /docker_container/config/* /docker_container/config_from_host
   fi
   python manage.py runserver
```